# How to use the bootstrap popover without jquery popover function and angular4 library in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, popover

```
<!-- Popover #1  used this html--> 
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-placement="top" data-
popover-content="#a1" data-toggle="popover" data-t 
trigger="focus" href="#" tabindex="0">Popover 
Example</a>

<!-- Content for Popover #1 -->
<div class="hidden" id="a1">
<div class="popover-heading">
This is the heading for #1
</div>
<div class="popover-body">
This is the body for #1
</div>
</div>
```

Used this html code, I need css for top,left,right and bottom
   AND trigger it with directive as I do not want to use jQuery
   Code or any library.

Comment: I wonder if you have tried https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started or do you wish to do it in old school way? Like downloading the bootstrap and then consuming it in Angular 4 application?

Comment: Bootstrap library is already added in my project.i don't want popover function to trigger it as i don't want to use jquery.so need same bootstrap 4 popover functionality.Using the same kind if html code mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

ngx-popover will solve your problem if you don't want to use jquery.

```
npm install ngx-popover --save
```

Comment: Thanks but i do not want to use library

Answer (score 0):

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api
this version of `ng-bootstrap` is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code.

I have the popover template in the html code:

```
<popover-content #myPopover 
      title="" 
      placement="bottom"
      [animation]="true" 
      [closeOnClickOutside]="true" >

      <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of notifications">
            <!-- <li class="list-group-item">{{item.name}}</li> -->
            <li class="list-group-item"><span>
                        <img  class="" src="assets/img/16.png" alt="" height="20px" width="20px" >
            </span>{{item.name}}</li>

      </ul>

      </popover-content>
```

then I use call this in a nav-item (you can use it wherever you want):

```
<li class="nav-item" [popover]="myPopover">
   <a class="nav-link " > Notificaciones</a>
</li>
```